# Excel VBA - increase accuracy of Match function

Tags: excel, match, vba

I am using a Match function in my program, its main purpose is to compare an input typed by the user and then loop into a database and do something every time there is a match.

**Currently, I am working with this :**

```
Function Match(searchStr As Variant, matchStr As Variant) As Boolean
Match = False
If (IsNull(searchStr) Or IsNull(matchStr)) Then Exit Function
If (matchStr = "") Or (searchStr = "") Then Exit Function

Dim f As Variant
f = InStr(1, CStr(searchStr), CStr(matchStr), vbTextCompare)
If IsNull(f) Then Exit Function
Match = f > 0

End Function
```

And then when it is used :

```
If Match(sCurrent.Range("A" & i).Value, cell.Value) Then
```

**Here is my problem :**

This is way too inaccurate. If I have in my database "Foxtrot Hotel", this function will find a match whenever the user types "F" "Fo" "Fox" "ox" "xtro" "t hot" and so on, so whenever there is a string of character included in the complete sentence.

What I want is to make my Match function identify only complete words. So in this case, to reveal a match only for three specific cases : "Foxtrot" "Hotel" and "Foxtrot Hotel".

I have read about an attribute called "lookat" which can do this kind of stuff with the Find function (lookat:=xlwhole), do you know if something similar can be inserted in my Match function?

Thanks !

Comment: Does `Cell.value` contain your database? And in what form - words separated by comma's etc?

Comment: On the one hand, you have one word only (in Range("A" & i) ), on the other hand, in Cell.Value you have words or succession of words, mostly separated by spaces (could be "Foxtrot", "Hotel Foxtrot" or "Capital Building Center" and so on). I'm gonna try what you suggested as an answer, thanks @brettdj !

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) like so. This one runs a case-insensitive match on whole words only (using word boundaries around the word being searched).

- False (*fo* is followed by a letter, not a word boundary)
- True
- True
- False (*FOXTROT h* not followed by a word boundary)

`Find` wont work with `xlWhole` for you - that will look to match the entire cell contents, not a single word within the contents.

```
Function WordMatch(searchStr As Variant, matchStr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "\b" & matchStr & "\b"
.ignorecase = True
WordMatch = .test(searchStr)
End With
Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function

Sub B()
Debug.Print WordMatch("foxtrot hotel", "fo")
Debug.Print WordMatch("foxtrot hotel", "hotel")
Debug.Print WordMatch("foxtrot hotel", "FOXTROT")
Debug.Print WordMatch("foxtrot hotel", "FOXTROT h")
End Sub
```